# Powershell code within a multithread that writes to a single log file, however some data is missed due to the file being in use

Tags: multithreading, powershell, logging

I am using PowerShell code within a multithread that writes to a single log file, however some data is missed due to the file being in use.  Is there a way to pause the thread until the file is unlocked?

Threaded output statement:

```
LogWrite "$Server, $SEPVersion, $AVFileVersionDate, Revision $AVRevisionKey, $SylinkGroup, $Boottime, $UpTime"   

#Main script

$MaxThreads = 4
StartLog
$filename = Get-FileName
$filecontents = Get-Content $filename

foreach ($server in $servers) {
  Start-Job -Name $Server -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -argumentlist $server 
  While($(Get-Job -State Running).Count -ge $MaxThreads) {
    Get-Job | Wait-Job -Any | Out-Null
  }
  Get-Job -State Completed | % {
    Receive-Job $_ -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
  }
}
While ($(Get-Job -State Running).Count -gt 0) {
  Get-Job | Wait-Job -Any | Out-Null
}
Get-Job -State Completed | % {
  Receive-Job $_ -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. Have your "master" script receive the output from the job and write it to the log (so you don't have concurrency issues). Otherwise have your code log to the eventlog or a similar facility that is capable of handling concurrent access.

Comment: The threads captures registry entries from a client and logs them, how would I have the Master script capture them instead:
From the Tread:  
LogWrite "$Server, $SEPVersion, $AVFileVersionDate, Revision $AVRevisionKey, $SylinkGroup, $Boottime, $UpTime"

Comment: Added code to the top of the thread

Comment: I guess it's not always desirable to wait for long-running jobs to return data to the parent before being flushed to file. You could write a Logger function or class  that opens/closes a stream to the file, attempts to write and retries on failures.

Comment: @Charlie Joynt - That is exactly what I was looking for as this will be run against a list of 1000s of workstations

Comment: You could run `Receive-Job` repeatedly (without `-AutoRemoveJob`, of course) in the loop that waits for job completion. Writing from the jobs will always have the concurrency issue.

Answer (score 3):

Change your logging function so that it accepts pipeline input (for more information about parameters see [`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)):

```
function LogWrite {
  Param(
    [Parameter(
      Mandatory=$true,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [string]$Message
  )

  ...
}
```

Change your scriptblock so that it simply echoes the output instead of writing to a file.

Then pipe the output collected by `Receive-Job` to your logging function:

```
Get-Job -State Completed | Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait | LogWrite
```

If you want to fetch output while the jobs are still running, you can do that from within the loop that waits for job completion:

```
While ($(Get-Job -State Running).Count -gt 0) {
  Get-Job | Receive-Job | LogWrite
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}
```

Comment: This is a neat solution. In the OP above whatever was returned by the ScriptBlock seems to be ignored. I guess this approach won't work if the ScriptBlock is returning something *other* than a load of events to log.